# access via post method input with integer name

Tags: php, html, post, input

If I have a form that contains many fields generated dynamically (their names are integer, because they are named after the iteration that generates them). I need to get their values via post or get (this is an issue i will deal with myself, so lets assume its post).

the code for the inputs:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < 5; $x++)
     for ($y = 0; $y < 12; $y++){
                        echo '<input type="text" name="'.$x.'"> Bar 1<br/>';  
     }
```

How can i get all the 12th values in an array on the server side using php? I generally know how to use post, but in this case what should i put inside the brackets of $_POST[]?
And what is the correct syntax to make the name an array?

Comment: As you have already said it's fixed so simply use $_POST['12']

Comment: you have 60 inputs ... => name=['.$x.']['.$y.']

Comment: I thought about it. But what complicates it is a function that i use to check the entire row with a special checkbox. If change the name like this, the function wont work aymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the post and ever 12th pull out a value just add a counter. If other posted information is in form, then do a preg match for first part of your key name and then iterate over counter on that name.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
 echo "Field ".htmlspecialchars($key)." is ".htmlspecialchars($value)."<br>";
```

If that approach isn't appealing, JSON encode the values being sent in an array to the php then do a json_decode into a php array and then take out every twelfth element.

Comment: does the solution with Json work even if i dont change the name of the checkboxes? Because if i change their name, i can't handle another script that is very important for other tasks

Comment: The method for json would be to add a function for the submit in JavaScript that would take the form values into an array then json encode them. Then send that string to your server side script in a submit. Make sure to use JSON.stringify(values) to json encode unless you have jquery then just use serialize

Answer (score 0):

Your code will produce twelve input fields with the same name (`$x`), which wont work (each input needs a unique name).

If I remember correctly, you can do something like this:

```
echo '<input type="text" name="'.$x.'[]"> Bar 1<br/>';
```

and it will generate an array in $_POST: `$_POST[$x][0] = 'first', $_POST[$x][1] = 'second', ...`